# pandas: Calculating the maximum of a blackman window: missing function pandas.core.window.Window.[max, apply]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, window, rolling-computation

In pandas, I am trying to calculate the maximum of a blackman window type of a rolling window of a `Series`. To accomplish this, I need to run a custom function over a rolling window with a `blackman` `win_type`. Unlike the default `win_type`, which returns a `pandas.core.window.Rolling`, any other `win_type` returns a `pandas.core.window.Window`, which lacks the methods required to compute this: `max` or a custom function via `apply`.

```
window = df['Net Volume'].rolling(window=range_window, win_type='blackman').max()
```

This results in: `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'max'`

So I try a custom `apply`:

```
window = df['Net Volume'].rolling(window=range_window, win_type='blackman').apply(lambda x: np.max(x))
```

And I get: `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'apply'`

I am at an impasse. How can I calculate the maximum of a blackman window of a `Window`? The `Window` object is much less useful than a `Rolling` object.

Comment: `iter` has not been yet implemented for Blackman windows (check [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704) ) so I'd guess getting the `max` is still not possible?

Comment: I figured it out. See solution.

Comment: Nice catch using `np.blackman` instead of `pd` ;)

Comment: Thanks! I don't often figure out smart shit! :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to use the default window for `pandas.core.Series.rolling` and then via `apply` with `raw=True` multiply a transposed `np.blackman` column vector (values ranged 0-1) to the window to effect your own `win_type='blackman'`. Then you `np.max` on this result:

```
df['Net Volume'].rolling(window=range_window).apply(
    lambda x: np.max(x * np.blackman(range_window)), raw=True
)
```

If someone could check this, I would appreciate it!